# Wait for multiple conditions then execute function

Tags: javascript, json, callback

Suppose I have three functions as such:

```
function A() {
   //does a jquery getJson() request and applies json data to html
   function C()
}

function B() {
   //does a jquery getJson() request and applies json data to html
   function C()
}

function C(){
   // applies cosmetic changes to the already set html which was made be Functions A & B.
   //for example it converts numbers 1-5 set in a span to starred rating.
}
```

The problem is that the functions A and B are async and their callback execution depends on the time taken of reception of json. and thus calling function C fails on one or the other dataset received by json.

So what I want is that function C should be executed ony after both the jsons are received and its data plotted onto the page. and it has to be called only once.

I have a feeling that this may be possible by closures but I am not sure.

Comment: Look for "promise pattern". You can do this easily with jQuery.

Comment: Ok. I will check it out.

Comment: So as per the three answers I got, They all somehow recommend synchronous execution. I wonder what may happen if the first json call fails.Maybe none others will execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Deferred Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) which deals with asynchronous calls for you. Doing so your code will be executed in the reading order, no matter when the response is sent back :

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON('url', function(data) {
    alert('first callback');
});
jqxhr.done(function() { 
    alert('second callback');
});
```

Then use [`jQuery.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to handle multiple deferred :

```
var jqxhr1 = $.getJSON('url1');
var jqxhr2 = $.getJSON('url2');
$.when(jqxhr1, jqxhr2).done(function(data1, data2) { 
    alert('both done');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the easiest way

```
function x() {
  var 
    aflag = false,
    bflag = false;

  function a() {
    // ajax
    aflag = true;
    c();
  }

  function b() {
    // ajax
    bflag = true;
    c();
  }

  function c() {
    if (aflag && bflag) {
        // it's ready 
    }
  }
}
```

but check this out https://github.com/stackp/promisejs#joining-functions

Comment: Well, this looks the most useful to me currently, I think if I can memoize the flags to the functions it would be better.

Comment: No problem this is a Vainilla solution though

Answer (score 1):

You can basically call the next function in the success callback of the current ajax call. That way you can stagger them in order

**EX:**

```
$.getJSON("/someurl", function() {
   B();
});
```

Comment: OK. So you mean that the second json call should only be initiated after the first json call goes a success.

Comment: Yes, the next call that depends on the result of the ajax call should be called from the success call back